# Doxygen not interpeting code block in md files

Tags: github, markdown, doxygen

I'm using doxygen to generate some documentation for some projects. I also use the following feature:

```
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = README.md
```

The problem is that the README.md files have the code blocks using ``` instead of ~~~

There is a way to tell doxygen to use process the ``` code blocks as well?

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you documenting and what variant of markdown are you expecting?  Straightforward markdown doesn't use either triplet marker for code blocks. (see http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode). Markdown Extra added ~~~~ code markers. Doxygen's interpretation is mainly vanilla MD with some 'Extra' support including that for ~~~ fences (but ~~~ only).